# How to always center window with grid but not elements?

Tags: html, css, grid

how can I have my grid container always stay centered but the elements with fixed width are still floating left, even on breaking? Just like in my example, but as shown, its not centered. Is there a need of js or is it fixable with css only? Thanks.

Here what I mean:

```css
#wrap {
  width: 100%;
  background: #f8f8f8;
  height: 300px;
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  margin: auto;
}

#item {
  background: white;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;
}

#item1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="container">
    <div id="item">
      <div id="item1"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="item">
      <div id="item1"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="item">
      <div id="item1"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="item">
      <div id="item1"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="item">
      <div id="item1"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="item">
      <div id="item1"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="item">
      <div id="item1"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="item">
      <div id="item1"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="item">
      <div id="item1"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="item">
      <div id="item1"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

<sup>***Note: Use `class` for multiple items instead of `id`. Same `id` should not be repeated in the code.***</sup>

You can use **[Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex)** here. Use `justify-content:center` for align center of items.

***Stack Snippet***

```css
#wrap {
  width: 100%;
  background: #f8f8f8;
  height: 300px;
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.item {
  background: white;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.item1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="container">
    <div class="item">
      <div class="item1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="item1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="item1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="item1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="item1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="item1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="item1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="item1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="item1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="item1"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you.. but on the breakpoint its not centered anymore, and that is my actual problem. and thanks for the advice with class

Comment: @Albeld it you wants items in center...I updated my answer using flex...Check above...

Comment: I was as far as you are now, but like you, I couldn't manage it, to have it floated left after breaking. Those 2 boxes are floating in the center, no way to have them left, but the whole still centered?

Comment: @Albeld you want those 2 boxes in center or left..?

Comment: @Albeld if you want them left..remove `justify-content:center`....See Updated answer

Comment: please check https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LQEBON and change the size of the result window (405px~), you will see its not centered on the breaking point. maybe i can explain it better with this way